# How can I use table CSS property all of my table except google custom search?

Tags: css, wordpress, google-custom-search

I am creating a website and I used google custom search for it. When I trying to add a border for th, td they also applied for my GCSE. It looks ugly when it appears there. I am trying to figure out how can I use my CSS code all table except google custom search. Here is my website, https://vendabariulo.gov.bd/citizen-charter/

Here is my code,

```
th, td {
text-align: left;
padding: 8px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Here is my search button screenshot, there shows a border around it. If I remove border from th, td it looks beautiful.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQPko.jpg)

Comment: don't style tags, use a class instead

Comment: Thanks, but It is a WordPress site, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all. After thinking and trying half an hour, I figure out something. It's work for me. I think it's a valid CSS rule.

I add a div class to my **google custom search** code and add this simple code,

```
.gcse td, th, tr {
border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to style the Google Custom Search itself.

This rule might help you

```
gsc-search-box th, gsc-search-box td {
    /* apply your rules here as you like.
    For example, border:none; */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use my CSS rule for all table format except GCSE. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @RanojitKumar, refer to my answer, is it what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Use `:not()` CSS pseudo-class as doctrine in [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

```
    table:not(table.gsc-search-box){ 

    /* your style definition */

        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;

     }
```

Hope it helps.